# Starcraft II Public Test?

Tags: starcraft-2

I have just realized there is a new menu item called "Starcraft II Public Test" which I think has been installed with one of the latest updates.

What is this?
I'm not very comfortable with launching executables whose function I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It launches a beta of the upcoming release of patch 1.2

Info: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/1334972

Comment: Did every user get this? It says I need a full US account, but I have an EU account. Downloaded game version in English though.  When I run it, it says that some server is not available.

Comment: @Bora From the article: To participate in the public test you must have a full North America product license.